# Translate standard output memory file to string of English text as if a print command were being used

Tags: python, unix, find, stdout, stringio

I am running a find command for a particular file that I know exists. I would like to get the path to that file, because I don't want to assume that I know where the file is located. My understanding is that I need to redirect stdout, run the command and capture the output, re-hook-up standard output, then retrieve the results. The problem comes when I retrieve the results... I can't decipher them:

```
import os
from cStringIO import StringIO
stdout_backup = sys.stdout #Backup standard output
stdout_output = StringIO() 
sys.stdout = stdout_output #Redirect standard output
os.system("find . -name 'foobar.ext' -print") #Find a known file
sys.stdout = stdout_backup #re-hook-up standard output as top priority
paths_to_file = stdout_ouput.get_value() #Retrieve results
```

I find all the paths I could want, the trouble is that paths_to_file yields this:

```
Out[9]: '\n\x01\x1b[0;32m\x02In [\x01\x1b[1;32m\x027\x01\x1b[0;32m\x02]: \x01\x1b[0m\x02\n\x01\x1b[0;32m\x02In [\x01\x1b[1;32m\x028\x01\x1b[0;32m\x02]: \x01\x1b[0m\x02'
```

I have no idea what to do with this. What I wanted was something like what the print command provides:

```
./Work/Halpin Programs/Servers/selenium-server.jar
```

How do I make that output usable for opening a file? If I can get what the print command yeilds, I can open the file I want.

Please reorient the question if I am misguided. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot capture the output of a subprocess by changing `sys.stdout`.  What you captured seems to be some ANSI escape sequences from your interactive Python interpreter (IPython?).

To get the output of an external command, you should use [`subprocess.check_output()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
paths = subprocess.check_output(["find", ".", "-name", "foobar.ext"])
```

In this particular case, I usually wouldn't call an external command at all, but rather use `os.walk()` to find the files from right within the Python process.

**Edit**: Here's how to use `os.walk()` to find the files:

```
def find(path, pattern):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for match in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
            yield os.path.join(root, match)

paths = list(find(".", "foobar.ext"))
```

Comment: Sven, thank you for your response. I'm about to test it. Do you mind elaborating the os.walk?